# Using ntop Win32 x86

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to compile [ntop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntop) under Win32. I download all files but at compile time 
many classes are missing?
Where could I find all needed source files for ntop?

Comment: Do not keep asking the same question over and over. DUPE - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772124/how-to-compile-ntop-under-windows

Answer (score 1):

Same place as the code on ntops website http://www.ntop.org/download.html You will need to register to get the full copy,